# Combine multiple groups in an aggregation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

If I have a collection like this:

```
{
    "store" : "XYZ",
    "total" : 100
},
{
    "store" : "XYZ",
    "total" : 200
},
{
    "store" : "ABC",
    "total" : 300
},
{
    "store" : "ABC",
    "total" : 400
}
```

I can get the `$sum` of orders in the collection by aggregation:

```
db.invoices.aggregate([{$group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: "$total"}}}])

{
    "result": [{
            "_id": null,
            "total": 1000
        }
    ],
    "ok": 1
}
```

And I can get the `$sum` of orders grouped by store:

```
db.invoices.aggregate([{$group: { _id: "$store", total: { $sum: "$total"}}}])

{
    "result": [{
            "_id": "ABC",
            "total": 700
        }, {
            "_id": "XYZ",
            "total": 300
        }
    ],
    "ok": 1
}
```

But how can I do this in one query?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could aggregate as below:

- `$group` by the `store` field, calculate the `subtotal`.
- `$project` a field `doc` to keep the `subtotal` group in tact, during the next
  group.
- `$group` by `null` and accumulate the net total.

**Code:**

```
db.invoices.aggregate([{
            $group: {
                "_id": "$store",
                "subtotal": {
                    $sum: "$total"
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project: {
                "doc": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "total": "$subtotal"
                }
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                "_id": null,
                "total": {
                    $sum: "$doc.total"
                },
                "result": {
                    $push: "$doc"
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project: {
                "result": 1,
                "_id": 0,
                "total": 1
            }
        }
    ])
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "total": 1000,
    "result": [{
            "_id": "ABC",
            "total": 700
        }, {
            "_id": "XYZ",
            "total": 300
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: just did! btw. on aggregation like this..is it more efficient to just call 2 separate calls for this sort of multiple groupings/projections?

Comment: @MattKim - Thank you. Though the aggregation solution involves more than a single stage, it works efficiently than making two database calls and then doing some post processing in the application code. the case would have been different if the solution involved some stages such as `$unwind`, which is very costly.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach would be using the `$facet` aggregation stage.

- `$facet` allows you to do multiple nested ***sub-aggregations***
  within your main aggregation.
- Each ***sub-aggregation*** has its own pipeline.
- For each result of a ***sub-aggregation*** we define another field.

Like this, for example:

```
db.invoices.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            total: [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        total: { $sum: "$total"}
                    }
                }
            ],
            store_totals: [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$store",
                        total: { $sum: "$total"}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },{
        $unwind: "$total"
    },{
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            total: "$total.total",
            store_totals: "$store_totals"
        }
    }
]
```

> @BatScream wrote, that an `$unwind` stage might be costly. However
>   we're unwinding an array of length 1 here. So I'm curious which
>   approach is more efficient under which circumstances. If someone can
>   compare those with `console.time()`, I'd be happy to include the
>   results.

---

#### Output

> Should be the same as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Is posible combine the results of each pipeline in that merge 1 document from facet A with other from facet B by unique field?. Like SQL when you can do subqueries _SELECT a,b,c  (SELECT ... LIMIT 1) as otherColumn  From T1_