# how to show only one data for the same property Handlebars?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

so i have this data:

```
    {
      item: "paint",
      unit: "4",
      price: "15",
      date : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:30:09")
    }
    {
      item: "paint",
      unit: "1",
      price: "5",
      date : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:30:15")
    }
    {
      item: "glue",
      unit: "2",
      price: "9",
      date : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:30:16")
    }
```

and my template is like this:

```
        {{#costs}}
          <p>{{item}} = {{unit}}</p>
        {{/costs}}
```

the result is gonna be like:

```
paint = 4
paint = 1
glue = 2
```

my question is, how to only show one data that has same property name (item) ?
so i can achieve something like this:

```
paint = 5
glue = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need aggregation pipeline to group the items and do a $sum. Also transform it to integer before summing.

```
db.test.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$item", totalUnits: { $sum: {$toInt: "$unit"}  }  }  }])
```

Above query will give you the outcome:

```
{ "_id" : "paint", "totalUnits" : 5 }
{ "_id" : "glue", "totalUnits" : 2 }
```

Comment: so i should use a helper with this aggregate ? sorry im kinda new on this

Comment: is it possible to achieve output :

paint = 5,
glue = 2,
total = 7

Comment: check the answer

Comment: thanks it works ! my next question is how to sum all of totalUnits ? i already find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420631/combine-multiple-groups-in-an-aggregation-in-mongodb but some how i can't fetch the data to my template.

Comment: If you want in the same query, you can just add another stage to the aggregation pipeline. I'd highly recommend watching MongoDB university courses related to aggregation pipeline.